# Exposed filters in Block for Page View do not filter results

Tags: views

I have below content types with following related fields setup in a Drupal7 setup.

Activity
    Fields: Name, Body and Image.

Event Fields:

- Date
- Location: Term Reference for Taxonomy Location
- Activity : Term Reference for Taxonomy Location
- Organiser: Entity Reference for Organizer node (as 1 event will have only 1 organizer)

Organiser
    Fields:

- Location: Term reference for Location taxonomy
- Activity: Entity  Reference for node Activity.

I have setup a Page View named Experience, with Listing of Events on right sidebar and on left sidebar i want to display the Filters.

I have managed to Expose the filter with BEF, however these filters don't give any result after changing value. Though they are set to Use Ajax.

Also other filters like Organiser and Location are autocomplete fields, these fields do not show-up any value on entering text.

Kindly help

UPDATE: Here's the SQL Query

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_field_event_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_event_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_event_location_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_event_amount_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_event_club} field_data_field_event_club ON node.nid = field_data_field_event_club.entity_id AND (field_data_field_event_club.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_event_club.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('event')) AND (field_data_field_event_club.field_event_club_target_id IS NOT NULL ) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your views filter is working when you disable ajax submit?

if No then `enable -> Show the SQL query`

from URL `www.yourdomain.com/admin/structure/views/settings`

then check query which is generating on submit of the form, you will get solution there only

try and let know status.

Comment: Under the Exposed form options ive set:
Autosubmit: No
Use AJAX: No

The filters still don't work, as you asked ive enabled Show SQL Query, but i am unable to interpret anything out of it.

Ive updated the question with the SQL Query, please have a look and let me know.

Comment: What is AND field in your form, i think issue is there in that field because on adding amount in both AND and amount field filter is working

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved, the problem was with the Operator that i had selected for the fileds.

I had selected `"Is not empty (NOT NULL)"` which wasnt giving any results, later i changed it to "Is one of" and it populated the field values correctly and the filters work.